# parse.com rest api to delete file iOS Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to delete a file in parse.com with a rest API and was wondering if the code was correct as nothing was deleting on the parse backend when i was testing the rest api code

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:file.url];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fileURL.pathComponents[2]];

//Creating the CURL request.
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.parse.com/1/files/%@", fileName];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *restAPI = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[restAPI setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];
[restAPI setValue:@"xxxxxx" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Application-Id"];
[restAPI setValue:@"xxxxxx" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Parse-Master-Key"];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:restAPI delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

i am trying to delete a file which is in a class called messages on the parse.com backend and its not working at the moment. The file column is the second column along in the class i think thats why i have `fileURL.pathComponents[2]`.

Why is it not working and can you help me fix the issue.

Comment: If the file is referenced by an object, the REST api cannot delete it.

Comment: @danh sorry for late reply, how do you mean. I save the data as a file and retrieve it as a file.